# Moodle Events API

Tags: php, events, moodle

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Moodle, using Events API that will send out emails when new blog post is created. I created my plugin with the following structure:

```
blog_observer/
├── classes
│   └── observer.php
├── db
│   └── events.php
└── version.php
```

`db/events.php`:

```php
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname'   => '\core\event\blog_entry_created',
        'callback'    => '\blog_observer\blog_observer::blog_created',
    ),
);
```

I got the event name from here [/blog/locallib.php](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/blog/locallib.php#L266).

`classes/observer.php`:

```php
namespace blog_observer;

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

class blog_observer {

    /**
     * The observer monitoring all the events.
     *
     * @param \core\event\base $event event object.
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function blog_created(\core\event\base $event) {
        file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r("observed an event", TRUE));

        return false;

    }
}
```

However I don't see that log, as if it doesn't even get to that class, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was the namespaces...

So the updated files are (I also renamed my plugin to `newsletter`):

```
newsletter/
├── classes
│   └── observer.php
├── db
│   └── events.php
└── version.php
```

`db/events.php`:

```php
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname'   => '\core\event\blog_entry_created',
        'callback'    => '\local_newsletter\observer::blog_created',
    ),
);
```

`classes/observer.php`:

```php
namespace local_newsletter;

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

class observer {

// The rest is same here

}
```